# image not loading in the browser in a cppcms example

Tags: html, c++, cppcms

I am trying to add a img tag in cppcms hello_world example. [I am following this page for the example](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_tut_hello). Following is the HTML code I am trying to render in browser

```cpp
        std::string str = "<html>\n"
        "<body>\n"
        "  <h1>Hello World</h1>\n"
        "<IMG SRC=\"abc.gif\">\n" /*this line is added by me*/
        "</body>\n"
        "</html>\n";

    response().out()<< str;
```

abc.gif is also in the same directory but when running the program the image is not being shown. Please suggest something.
edit:

[image: added the output of network shown by the browser]

Comment: What do you see when you open the network monitor of your browser?

Comment: I have edited the post with the result shown by the network monitor.

Comment: What do you see when you open `/abc.gif` in your browser? It looks like there is no routing in your server and get the same response for all routers. You can also try to open `/DoesNotExist`.

Comment: When giving the absolute location of the image in the browser, it shows the image. But as cppcms start a localhost server, the image is not being loaded in that case.

Comment: What is the absolute location of the image?

Comment: image and the program are in the same directory.

Comment: With the provided information it's nearly impossible to help. You don't answer the questions. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have added a link to the example I am following. I am just adding a img tag but it is not being loaded in the browser.

Comment: Ok, so there is an example that probably works. And there is a project on your computer that doesn't work and that we can't see. How do you expect us to help you? And there is no image in the example.

Comment: I am expecting a help because I am informing you everything you are asking me. What else you want me to do? If you have worked with cppcms, you could help me.

Comment: I said in my second comment _"It looks like there is no routing in your server"_. That's the problem. But you said _"When giving the absolute location of the image in the browser, it shows the image."_ I tried to analyze it but you didn't answer my questions.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how it can be solved?

Comment: Add a routing to your server http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_tut_url_mapping

Comment: Why do I require adding routing just to add a img tag? [http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_tut_url_mapping](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_tut_url_mapping) shows an example when the URL is needed to be mapped.

Comment: Because `localhost:8080/` and `localhost:8080/abc.gif` are two different routes but your server will send the same response. The response has to be different depending on the route. You have to map the route `/abc.gif` to a file response containing the image and the route `/` to your index page.

Comment: You should read about the basics of HTML and how a browser works. Your browsers sends a request with the URL to the server. If the response is a HTML file, your browser parses the file. If the file contains links, e.g. links to an image, your browser sends a new request with the URL of the image. Your server has to handle this request differently. That's called routing.